# How to generate JAVA RMI stubs and skeletons from Interface?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, rmi

Is there an action (menu / shortcut) that I miss or plug-in to add to a basic JavaEE distribution of Eclipse 3.5 that will allow to generate / regenerate files that usualy done from command line call for rmic?

I am aware of the ["RMI Plug-in for Eclipse version 2.0"](http://www.genady.net/rmi/v20/) I am looking for a free one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rmic is no longer needed since java 5:
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/relnotes.html

Sun's RMI was too inconvenient for development and many people came up with 'light weight rmi' replacements. Java5's simplification on RMI didn't make news because haters already moved on to other alternatives.

Comment: Wow! Missed this news! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this open source one](http://rmi-eclipse.sourceforge.net/)